# Python - cx_Freeze error with a script

Tags: python, exe, cx-freeze

So basically I have a problem with a script I wrote which organizes directories. It gets the directory name and is supposed to be ran on the directory the person wishes to organize. Although after turning it into .exe with cx_Freeze I can't run it on the directory I want because it will be missing the files from the build. I'm wondering if there's a solution or if I have to change the script to get the directory path in another way.

The script is in: https://github.com/JoaoBordaloo/PyProjects/blob/master/File%20Organizer%20v2/organize.py
in case you need to take a look

Comment: Can you add some code on the question?

Comment: This not work on `Unicode filename` ! Like this: `Ser\xfc.png`. so accepted files and directories with default encoding. What is your encoding ? Another question:  did you have all file permission in a directory ?

Comment: @pableiros I think the it's more about the cx_Freeze process but I would have to add all the code on the program. That's why I added the github. If you can't access it I can put the whole code in here

Comment: @dsgdfg I don't really understand what you mean tbh. I'm kinda new so ye..

Comment: A short information  : `OS` level operations got `OS encoding` style ! Need use python 3+ or unicode directory/file names.

Comment: @dsgdfg I'm using python 3.4 since cx_Freeze apparently doesn't exist for 3.5 yet. I will search online what you mean to learn about it. ty. Any ideas tho on how I could turn that specific script into executable? Cause if it's in the build directory it opens but apparently doesn't perform the operations

Comment: On your script : `path = os.getcwd() to os.getcwdu()` and verry importan point **Use Logging if create an exe(win app)** , so `try:`and `except Exception,e: log.write(str(e))`

Comment: @dsgdfg I will take a look into that thank you